# How to find unused factor levels?

Tags: r, enums, r-factor

I have data frame with "State" column, which is a factor with US State.

Not all states are present among values, while all states are among factor levels.

How to find factor levels, which are never used in the data frame?

Comment: If you look at the factor variable all the levels are printed

Comment: How to use this fact programmatically?

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
# A toy factor variable:
f <- factor(letters[1:2], levels = letters[1:4])
f
[1] a b
Levels: a b c d
levels(f)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

To see the unused levels:

```
setdiff(levels(f), f)
[1] "c" "d"
```

Comment: This is nice. Might it be more efficient to do `setdiff(levels(f), unique(f))` for long vectors?